# List appended in function doesn't work

Tags: python

This is my class:

```
from Student import Student
class Class:
    stulist=[]
    def __init__ (self, classname, numstudents):
        self.classname=classname
        self.numstudents=numstudents
    def addStudent(self, stuNum, stuName, stuGrades):
        Class.stulist.append(Student(stuName, stuGrades))
    def getPlace(self):
        print (Class.stulist[0].printLn()) #printLn is function in Student 
        print (Class.stulist[1].printLn())
        print (Class.stulist[2].printLn())
```

This is my runner:

```
from Class import Class

class ClassRunner():
        def main():
            test=Class("Comp sci 1", 3)
            test.addStudent(0, "Jimmy","4 - 100 90 80 60")
            test.addStudent(1, "Sandy","4 - 100 100 80 70")
            test.addStudent(2,"Fred","4 - 50 50 70 68")
            test.getPlace()
        main()
```

my output shows:

Fred = 50 50 70 68

Fred = 50 50 70 68

Fred = 50 50 70 68

But i want it to show:

Jimmy = 100 90 80 60

Sandy = 100 100 80 70

Fred = 50 50 70 68

what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your `Class` class, `self.stulist` instead of `Class.stulist`.

You are modifying the class itself, not the instance variable.

```
class Class:
    stulist=[]
    def __init__ (self, classname, numstudents):
        self.classname=classname
        self.numstudents=numstudents
    def addStudent(self, stuNum, stuName, stuGrades):
        self.stulist.append(Student(stuName, stuGrades))
    def getPlace(self):
        print (self.stulist[0].printLn()) #printLn is function in Student 
        print (self.stulist[1].printLn())
        print (self.stulist[2].printLn())
```

References to `Class` are going to modify the actual `Class` object itself.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Coder if it worked, you can hit the checkmark  so that I know this answer solves your issue.